# Ошибка! Строковые функции работают некорректно

Tags: php, битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]восстановил из бэкапа сайт на битриксе, в поле `Параметры настройки UTF (mbstring и константа BX_UTF)`  вылезла ошибка - `Ошибка! Строковые функции работают некорректно.Такая ситуация может возникать из-за ошибки в PHP 5.6 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68644), в этом случае надо установить более раннюю или более позднюю версию PHP.` пробовал всякие варианты, то всё падает, то не помогает.. прошу помочь разобраться с этим. Ошибка, которую выводит php на самом сайте выглядит так `Call to undefined function mb_orig_strtolower()`

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что такой функции нет, а она где то вызывается. Какие варианты Вы пробовали ? Приложите то, что Вы испробовали и каков был результат (логи)

Comment: Смотрите, ситуация слегка изменилась.. я узнал, что мне php обновили до 7.4.9 так как версия битрикса была старой, я его решил обновить до самого нового варианта. Ошибка изменилась, теперь при проверке системы, в поле UTF выводится ошибка `Ошибка! Строковая функция strlen работает некорректно.`

Comment: ошибка вылезла оказывается из-за php, я установил значения mbstring.func_overload=2
default_charset=utf-8

Comment: думаю сейчас на mbstring.func_overload в master value, но не знаю, почему применилось только в local

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема в самом битриксе. Он не работает корректно с версиями php выше чем 7.2, подтверждения этому здесь - https://habr.com/ru/post/465609/ , здесь - https://qna.habr.com/q/687179 и здесь - https://qna.habr.com/q/834803
если у кого-нибудь есть положительный опыт перехода на версии php 7.3+, прошу рассказать.